# Wake up Android Phone/tablet?

Tags: android, push-notification, push, wakelock, wakeup

I've got a push notification-app, is there any way to wake up the screen (just make it light up) whenever I receive a push notification?

if you want some code just let me know! and Thank you for your answers!

Comment: You shoudl use this tutorial http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html or use wake lock in andrid

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it using a `WakeLock` this way:

When you set your notification:

```
WakeLock screenOn = ((PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE)).newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "example");
screenOn.acquire();
```

And, *IMPORTANT*, release the wakelock when you don't need it anymore:

```
screenOn.release();
```

Comment: Remember about <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

Comment: What about the now deprecated SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK?

Comment: How about if we want to skip security lock screens (PIN, Patterns etc)?