# wake up after notification and delete after exit xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I need to wake up android after receive notification and delete them after exit from app in xamarin. If phone not in sleep mode notification working well, but after turn in sleep i can only hear notification sound and nothing else.

AlarmReciever.cs

```
public class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        NotificationManager manager;
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {

            string message = intent.GetStringExtra("message");
            string title = intent.GetStringExtra("title");

            Intent notIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, notIntent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
            manager = NotificationManager.FromContext(context);
            var style = new Notification.BigTextStyle();
            style.BigText(message);

            int resourceId = Resource.Drawable.icon;

            var wearableExtender = new Notification.WearableExtender()
    .SetBackground(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(context.Resources, resourceId))
                ;

            //Generate a notification with just short text and small icon
            var builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.Max)
                .SetVisibility(NotificationVisibility.Public)
                .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.All)
                .SetCategory(Notification.CategoryAlarm)
                .SetContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
                .SetContentTitle(title)
                .SetContentText(message)
                .SetWhen(Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis())
                .SetAutoCancel(true);

            var notification = builder.Build();
            manager.Notify(0, notification);
        }
}
```

AndroidReminderService.cs

```
public class AndroidReminderService : IReminderService
    {
        public void Remind(int seconds, string title, string message)
        {

            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(Forms.Context, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
            alarmIntent.PutExtra("message", message);
            alarmIntent.PutExtra("title", title);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Forms.Context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);

            alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtimeWakeup, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + seconds * 1000, pendingIntent);
        }
```

}

IReminderService.cs

```
public interface IReminderService
    {
        void Remind(int seconds, string title, string message);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide some details such as what you've tried already, what resources you've read, and an overall goal of what you are trying to accomplish.

You can use a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` to ensure that a device wakeup event will then pass the work off to a `Service` which will ensure the device does not go back to sleep.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html

Comment: I also see that this may have been answered already as for how to wake the device on receiving a notification: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977448/wake-up-android-phone-tablet