# Notifications in Android when the phone is sleeping

Tags: android, notifications

I have been using Notifications in an app I am building. The way to build notification has changed a lot since older versions it seems, but in the end I managed to display a notification. (*)

I have two problems though: 
1) The notification makes no sound. It is not a matter of increasing the volume of notifications in the tablet because notifications from gmail for example do produce sound. How do I make a notification that produce sound and vibration? (I am trying this in Android 6)

2) Even more important, how do I make a notification that "notifies" me even when the phone is sleeping? So far my notifications *do* happen when the phone is sleeping but I have to turn on the phone to see them. Ideally these should appear even when the screen is black

EDIT: just to be clear, the notifications *are* happening when the phone is sleeping. It is just that I don't see them unless I turn on the screen, then they are. I would like for the notification to "turn on the screen"

(*) My current code is

```
         NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(), 0);


        Notification notification= new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(message)
                .setContentText("Proximity Alert!")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pi).build(); //getNotification();


        //notification.flags= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        //notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "GAST", "Proximity Alert", pi); //this is deprecated

        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: for sound:  Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);  and in notification builder:  .setSound(defaultSoundUri)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can add sound while sending notification with this way.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);  

Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICAT‌​ION); 
builder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);
```

And to do it while sleeping phone you will have to use service.

Documentation : [Services](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. About the second item, I may have not explained myself well, sorry. The notification **does happen** while sleeping. If I press the on button I can clearly see that there they are even without using services. My problem is I want them to wake up the phone. How can I do that?

Comment: Refer this to wake up screen

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977448/wake-up-android-phone-tablet)

Hope this helps